# When using python-markdown what determines the "final" look of the page?

Tags: python, markdown

When using [python-markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) what determines the *final look* of the page?

I.e. what do I need to change, for example and more importantly where, to let's say, change the color of the H1 headers from black to light blue?

Comment: @JBernardo - Could you be just a bit more elaborate?

Comment: @JBernardo - Is it possible to have it use the css file that will be in the same folder as the original markdown/final html file?

Comment: add a style to the html page (e.g. mystyle.css) and add `h1 { color: blue; } ` inside it

Answer (score 0):

As @JBernardo pointed out in his comment you'll need some CSS. This means that since the HTML output from `python-markdown` doesn't contain any style, you have to add it yourself to the HTML document and the easiest way to do that is with CSS.

To do that, just make sure that you add a reference to the CSS file in the HTML or that you include the whole style in the HTML document. You'll find more information about how to do that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

With regard to your question, to set `h1` color all you need in your CSS is something as:

```
h1 { color: <color> }
```

Comment: I could add it to a single html. But what would I need to to to modify the plugin so it always "links" to a let's say, style.css file which would always be in the directory along with the .markdown and the resulting .html files?

Comment: I'd say that's not part of what `python-markdown` should do, but the template engine you're using. For example, if you're using django, [here](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django) you can find some documentation.